# codeigniter load models error

Tags: php, codeigniter

hi I am new to codeigniter
I am trying to load a model inside a controller and I get
`Fatal error: Class 'application\models\CI_Model'` not found.
Do I need to set something up before I load the model

**My Controller:**

```
class VerifyLogin extends CI_Controller{

        function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('user','',TRUE);
        }

        function index(){

            $this->load->library('form_validation');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|min_length[6]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]');

            if ($this->form_validation->run()==false)
            {
                $this->load->view('header');
                $this->load->view('marketing/marketing_custom_header');
                $this->load->view('menu_2');
                $this->load->view('marketing/marketing');
                $this->load->view('footer');
            }else{
                redirect('home', 'refresh');
            }

        }

    }
```

**My Model:**

```
    class User extends CI_Model {

        function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
        }



         function  login($email,$password ){
             $this->db ->select('id, email, password');
             $this->db -> from('users');
             $this->db -> where('email',$email);
             $this->db -> where('password',$password);
             $this->db -> limit(1);

             $query ="";
             $query ->$this ->db ->get();
             if($query ->num_rows()==1){
                 return $query->resilt();
             }else{
                 return false;
             }
         }


    }
```

Comment: The code is looking fine. Is there a specific reason you have passed `TRUE` while loading the model.

Comment: what is the name of your model file and where it is located in your application?

Comment: the reason to pass TRUE is for connecting to DB.

Comment: name of the module file user.php

Comment: and it is in the models

Answer (score 0):

**Check following points -**

- It's obviously not being able to find the class **`CI_Model`** which should be in **`system/core/Model.php`**.
- Make sure the file is still there and the **`filename`** hasn't changed for some reason, and that there is no **`typo`** within the file.
- In the main **`index.php`** (the one that resides outside of **`applications`** and **`system`** directories), make sure **`$system_path`** is set correctly.
- Your model file should be in **`applications/models/`** directory have the `file name` same as `class name` i.e **user.php**

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help 
My IDE added namespace application\models;
That was the problem